# How do you get the sum of the product of two properties in an IEnumerable using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` from an SQL query using Dapper, and I would like to add together the product of two properties of the dynamic objects in the `IEnumerable`.

I tried:

```
decimal total = orderDetails.Aggregate((workingTotal, detail) => 
    workingTotal + (detail.quantity * detail.unitPrice));
```

but that returns an `object` that cannot be converted to a decimal.

Comment: `cannot be converted` - what do you mean? did you try casting it to a decimal? if `detail` is a `dynamic` then you'll need to cast to the type you want, as there's no known type information compile time.

Comment: have you tried var total instead of decimal total in order to see what is returned?

Comment: Have you tried using `Sum`? `decimal total = orderDetails.Sum(detail => (decimal) (detail.quantity * detail.unitPrice));`. (You may not need the cast at all...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I tried something similar to that, but without the cast. That answer worked for me. Please put that in an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Sum` instead of `Aggregate`:

```
decimal total = orderDetails.Sum(x => (decimal) (x.quantity * x.unitPrice));
```

Depending on exactly what your situation is, I can imagine this potentially working without any casts, or needing more casts... it's not always easy to tell with `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know the types of `detail.quantity` and `detail.unitPrice`, so you need to cast them.
Also, you need [another `Aggregate` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx), one with a seed value:

```
decimal total = orderDetails.Aggregate((decimal)0, (workingTotal, detail) =>
            workingTotal + ((decimal)detail.quantity * (decimal)detail.unitPrice));
```

Of course, you can use a `Sum` instead of an `Aggregate` - much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with dynamics, the compiler doesn't know what `detail.quantity`, etc are. So you need to explicitly cast it to a `decimal`.

```
decimal total = (decimal)orderDetails.Aggregate((workingTotal, detail) => 
     workingTotal + (detail.quantity * detail.unitPrice));
```